# JSON in CDATA in XML - works on localhost(WAMP), but not on hosting(LINUX)

Tags: php, javascript, xml, linux, json

PHP

```
echo '<data><![CDATA[ [{"x":0,"y":0,"src":"images/image.jpg"}]  ]]></data>';
```

JS

```
$.post( 'getData.php', {}, _onResult );

_onResult = function( result)
{
    console.log(result); 
}
```

The above console.log outputs:

( on localhost, using WAMP ):

```
<data><![CDATA[ [{"x":0,"y":0,"src":"images/image.jpg/"}]  ]]></data>
```

( on web hosting, using LINUX ):

```
<data><![CDATA[ [{"/x/":0,/"y/":0,/"src/":/"images/image.jpg/"}]  ]]></data>
```

How can I get the same output in the second case?

or

Can I somehow convert the second output to be able to parse it with $.parseJSON ?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you wrapping JSON in XML?

Comment: @Evan, This is just a simplified version of data for the purpose of this question. I will get it all converted to json, but for now I need to get it working like this. Does it answer your question? :)

Comment: Not really, but it's not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with your script..

```
var xml = "<data>\
        <![CDATA[ [{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"src\":\"images/image.jpg\"}]  ]]>\
    </data>";
var dataXML = $.parseXML(xml);
var json = $(dataXML).find('data').text();

console.log(json); // outputs [{"x":0,"y":0,"src":"images/image.jpg"}]
```

No error in this line too

```
var json = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, are testing this on linux?

Comment: no i have checked on Chrome Browser on Windoes OS... AFAIK its OS independent.. donot think about OS linux/windows/Mac will work.

Comment: From your answer I can see that there should be \ slashes when receiving it on the client side, so they need to be added in php I suppose (addslashes).

Comment: i dont think you need to add. i have added in my answer because i jus did that in javascript. your php echo seems fine. im jus confused where you r getting the output `[{"/x/":0,/"y/":0,/"src/":/"images/image.jpg/"}]`.???!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be about the browser, or the HTTP server reading the XML data and not automatically parsing it to be a JSON object due to the security reasons. Whatever the reason, this line is (by assuming automatic conversion) fails:

```
 var json = $(dataXML).find('data').text();
```

Instead, change it with this:

```
 var json = $.parseJSON($(dataXML).find('data').text()); // i think you can use $.parse() too.
```

This problem have occured to me a few times in various occasions on both platforms before, and I don't think a stable thing. Howeever, since there is no way that the browser (or JS interpreter) can "detect" that it's actually a JSON object (inside that XML), you must explicitly define it to be so, if you want to establish type safety of your stuff (which is a good programming method).

PS: "localhost" is very flexible about security, so I'd recommend not to rely on it very much :)